# E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer

Tags: software-installation, docker, java, oracle

I've been using the below Dockerfile to install java8. However, all of a sudden while creating the docker image it breaks with error

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-set-default
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty-20151218

ENV JAVA_VER 8
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

RUN echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo 'deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C2518248EEA14886 && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-installer oracle-java${JAVA_VER}-set-default && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk${JAVA_VER}-installer \
    echo 'APT::Install-Recommends 0;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01norecommends \
    && echo 'APT::Install-Suggests 0;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01norecommends \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y vim.tiny wget sudo net-tools ca-certificates unzip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: You're a couple months behind everybody else. Crossdupes https://serverfault.com/questions/964736/oracle-jdk-is-no-longer-available-downloading-from-the-webupd8team https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946245/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920389/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771797/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55900297/